# How to convert FlowDocument to rtf 

Tags: c#, rtf, flowdocument

I have used a WPF RichTextBox to save a flowdocument from it as byte[] in database. Now i need to retrieve this data and display in a report RichTextBox as an rtf.
when i try to convert the byte[] using TextRange or in XAMLReader i get a FlowDocument back but how do i convert it to rtf string as the report RichTextBox only takes rtf.

Thanks

Arvind

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a code sample? What differs between you code and Peter's answer (which seems workable according to MSDN)?

Comment: I found this link looks very helpful http://matthewmanela.com/blog/converting-rtf-to-html/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should not persist the FlowDocument directly as it should be considered the runtime representation of the document, not the actual document content. Instead, use [the TextRange class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598701.aspx) to Save and Load to various formats including [Rtf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataformats.rtf.aspx).

A quick sample on how to create a selection and save to a stream:

```
var content = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

if (content.CanSave(DataFormats.Rtf))
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        content.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}
```

To load content into a selection would be similar:

```
var content = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

if (content.CanLoad(DataFormats.Rtf))
{
    content.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce but i have tryed this method and this this does not save the formating made in the text(ie making text bold changing colour),i need to also the save the format so i save it as a flowDodcument

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm for me. Displays the result in an RTF box without difficulties.

```
public static string getDocumentAsXaml(IDocumentPaginatorSource flowDocument)
{
     return XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
    Using conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionSTRING)
       Dim adapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(selectSTRING, conn)
       Dim DS As System.Data.DataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
       adapter.Fill(DS)

       Dim ba() As Byte = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("RTF_Field").ToString())

       Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(ba)
       Dim fd As FlowDocument = New FlowDocument
       Dim tr As TextRange = New TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd)
       tr.Load(ms, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf)
       ms.Close()

            RichTextBox.Document = fd

        End Using
```

You will need to use your connection string & SQL select statement ... other than that, this is it ...

Comment: He doesn't address the problem.  The code just reads an RTF string from a binary database field (as ASCII >.<), and then loads it into a flow document as RTF.

Comment: Accepted Answer: use the TextRange class to Save and Load to various formats including Rtf.

Comment: The solution offered here uses textrange to load memorystream, DataFormats.RTF ... same as accepted ... just displayed a field grab  ... you guys troll much >.<