# Showing Database rtf data in richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, richtextbox, xamlparseexception

I write WPF application. In this application user copy data from the word document and add it to richtextbox. Then I save this data in sqlite database. 
But when I get xaml data from data base and do following procedure

```
// Saving data
StringWriter wr = new StringWriter();
XamlWriter.Save(RichTextBox.Document, wr);
```

and

```
FlowDocument doc = XamlReader.Parse(*wrStringValuefromDB*) as FlowDocument;
```

End of this process richtextbox concatenate some words as follow:[image]

I can't understand what is happening here, Please help me.

Now I know that this problem happens some PC or OS. For example, I install application on Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and it work very good. But some PC doesn't. For example:
[image]

Comment: Why do you use an XamlWriter? Can't you simply store the content in the db? I expect you have an encoding issue somwhere in that code path.

Comment: I am new in WPF. I watched many example for saving richtextbox content to database, and this approach is advanced I saw.

Comment: @rene, Have you any suggestion to save richtextbox content to database with another way?

Comment: You could try to XamlWriter.Save to a MemoryStream, store the byte[] in the db and on retrieval create a memoryStream again from that byte array and use the XamlReader.Load() instead of Parse. But that is all I have to offer.

Comment: thanks, @rene. I will try it

Comment: Have you determined whether the problem exists in saving/restoring the richtextbox from XAML, or saving/restoring the XAML from sqlite?  I.e. if you just write to XAML and immediately restore from XAML, does your rich text box get corrupted?

Comment: If it is corrupted, Why app works some PC with same text? The data coped from Word file and past into the rchtextbox.

Comment: See ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829053/how-to-convert-flowdocument-to-rtf
Maybe this is your problem!?

Comment: @Tom, I need formatted text

Comment: @Elvin Mammadov allthough it's called TextRange() it is formatted Text

Comment: Ok, I will try its now))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ... stackoverflow.com/questions/829053/… Maybe this is your problem!?
Allthough it's called TextRange() it is formatted Text.