# How can I save WPF RichTextBox in databse without lost links?

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

I have a Link in Richtextbox and it works good but if I save that Richtextbox in to database and then load it that link to be deleted and I just can see the text of that Link

for example my Richtextbox have bottom text:

[This is a link](http://google.com)

But after save and load again I just can see the text:

This is a link

The hyperlink created dynamically from selected text as bellow:

```
            RichTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled = true;

            RichTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;

            Run run = new Run(RichTextBox.Selection.Text);
            Hyperlink hyp = new Hyperlink(run) { TargetName = run.Text };
            TERM.WordMain main = new TERM.WordMain();

            hyp.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(main.hyperLink_Click);
            hyp.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://search.msn.com");
            RichTextBox.Cut();

            var container = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock(hyp), RichTextBox.Selection.Start);
            RichTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled = true;
            RichTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
```

Saving richtextbox content as RTF format to text field:

```
 public static string ToStringFromBytes(System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        if (richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

        textRange.Save(memoryStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
```

And load from database to **flowdocument**

```
public static FlowDocument LoadFromString(string s)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s));

            FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();

            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd);

            textRange.Load(stream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);

            return doc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I add some codes for example.

Comment: Does the `Paragraph` object get stored with the `Hyperlink` in the collection along with the other `Run` objects? This will tell you whether it's the save or load code that's failing.

Comment: @ChrisF, I cant understand the question.

Comment: Do you just store the text or do you store the XAML markup as well?

Comment: First of all i save as Xaml format,, But after this I lost hyperlink. Then I search and find that for saving hyperlinks or images to database it must save in RTF format as string,, but after this I lost link ability of hyperlinks

Comment: I have an application where I save the xaml and it all works fine. You need to use the RichTextBox's `Xaml` property when reading from it or setting it up.

Comment: ok, First application work. But after this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434975/showing-database-rtf-data-in-richtextbox I change functinality of its. So then I can't save data as xaml because I lost hyper link.

Comment: @ChrisF,  I add hyperlink yo word document, and then save and load it. Hyperlink is shown. I think that there is a problem in creating dynamic hyperlink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sample seems to do the trick.

Here I load and save the `XAML` instead of the text in rtf format. Note also that you need to add handlers for the hyperlinks back to the elements after loading, since they will not be serialized.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private const string _stateFile = "state.xaml";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        richTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
    }

    private void createLinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled = false;
        richTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
        var textRange = richTextBox.Selection;
        var hyperlink = new Hyperlink(textRange.Start, textRange.End);
        hyperlink.TargetName = "value";
        hyperlink.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://search.msn.com");
        hyperlink.RequestNavigate += HyperlinkOnRequestNavigate;
        richTextBox.IsDocumentEnabled = true;
        richTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
    }

    private void HyperlinkOnRequestNavigate(object sender,
        RequestNavigateEventArgs args)
    {
        // Outputs: "Requesting: http://search.msn.com, target=value" 
        Console.WriteLine("Requesting: {0}, target={1}", args.Uri, args.Target);
    }

    private void SaveXamlPackage(string filePath)
    {
        var range = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
            richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        var fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        range.Save(fStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        fStream.Close();
    }

    void LoadXamlPackage(string filePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            var range = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            var fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
            fStream.Close();
        }

        // Reapply event handling to hyperlinks after loading, since these are not saved:
        foreach (var paragraph in richTextBox.Document.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>())
        {
            foreach (var hyperlink in paragraph.Inlines.OfType<Hyperlink>())
            {
                hyperlink.RequestNavigate += HyperlinkOnRequestNavigate;
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveXamlPackage(_stateFile);
    }

    private void loadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadXamlPackage(_stateFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @steinar. How to add TargetName to hyperlink? Beause I use it in click event

Comment: You can just add `hyperlink.TargetName = "...";` in the method `createLinkButton_Click`. That value is then serialized on save so you don't need to reapply it when loading.

Comment: I add it but it return empty string value(

Comment: Now I use another way,, add it to Navigateuri then get the value))). but I can't understand why TargetName is emplty

Comment: That's strange, take a look at the edited answer, I've added the `TargetName` there and it does work as expected in my case. Maybe your code differs somehow.

Comment: I add as you, but doesn't work. TargetName is empty((((. How can this happen?

Comment: What is a stupid problem I can't understand. My customer wait me, but it doesn't work (((((((((((